# Text gets stretched or disappears when scrolling

Tags: bug, android-app

When scrolling in the Stack Exchange Android app, the text gets stretched vertically, code disappears, and sometimes the entire post content disappears.  This doesn't make the app completely useless, but it's pretty close.

Motorola Razr MAXX, Android 4.0.4.

[image] [image] 
[image]

Comment: Do you have this on other sites?

Comment: I meant to ask if this happens on other sites outside of the SE network ;)

Comment: Whoops, wrong tag. I get this on the StackExchange Android app. I fixed the tags to clarify this.

Comment: Same problem here... Quite annoying. Huawei ascend p1 LTE on android 4.0.4

Comment: No stretching for me on 4.2.2, but a weird blinking effect and some large "empty" areas in answers after the content (not entirely unlike your last screenshot, but with the content still visible).

Comment: No stretching problem on 4.4.4 but I think here the resolution of the device could be the problem? I do get some white areas when scrolling.

Comment: Probably have something to do with pixel density yes..

Comment: I also see this.  HTC Evo 3D, Android 4.0.3.

Comment: I posted a bug report for this as well, and it got merged into this one. This is a very annoying bug affecting a lot of Android users that got stuck with 4.0.x due to the absence of updates, and it makes the app unusable to a degree where I'd straight-up uninstall it.